What is this kind of undirected metric tree called?
Definition of object of interest
Suppose you have an undirected metric tree $T=(V,E,w)$ where $V$ is the set of vertices, $E$ is the set of edges and the function $w:E\to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ describes the weights of the edges.
Okay so I wish to add more structure to this object, specifically, something that describes the specific cyclic permutation of the neighbors of a vertex. Here's what I came up with:

Let's denote the neighbors of arbitrary vertex $v\in V$ as set $N_v$, that is the set of all vertices adjacent to $v$ (not including $v$). Formally, $N_v:=\{u\in V\ |\ \{u,v\}\in E\}$

For a finite set $A$, we say the function $S:A\to A$ is a cyclic permutation of $A$ if and only if, starting at any arbitrary element $a\in A$, we can obtain any element $b\in A$ by applying $S$ to $a$ some number of times. That is, there exists a number $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $b=S^{n}(a)$. Let $A$ have $n$ elements, $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in A$, let $\langle x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n\rangle$ denote the cyclic permutation that maps $x_n$ to $x_1$, $x_1$ to $x_2$, $x_2$ to $x_3$, etc.


Now we say $T'=(V,E,w,\text{rot})$ is a special undirected metric tree if and only if $(V,E,w)$ is an undirected metric tree and function $\text{rot}:V\to (V\to V)$ maps arbitrary vertex $v\in V$ to some cyclic permutation of $N_v$ denoted $\text{rot}_v$.
If $\text{rot}_v(u)=w$ we say $w$ is clockwise of $u$ with respect to $v$ in $T'$, or equivalently, $u$ is counter-clockwise of $w$ with respect to $v$ in $T'$.
My main question
I'm sure that this "special metric tree" has been studied before / has a more descriptive name but I don't know what it's called. What is this kind of metric tree called? Thank you.
Examples of "special metric trees"
Consider these three special metric trees, labeled $H$ for "hand", $G$ for "giraffe" and $D$ for "dragonfly." Here are images of these special metric trees embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$:
embedding of $H$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$
embedding of $G$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$
embedding of $D$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$
The definitions of $H$,$G$ and $D$ respectively are as follows:
$H=(V_1,E_1,w_1,\text{rot1})$ with

$V_1=\{\text{thumb},\text{index},\text{middle},\text{ring},\text{pinkey},\text{palm},\text{elbow}\}$
$E_1=\{\{\text{palm},\text{other}\}\ |\ \text{other}\in V_1, \text{other}\neq \text{palm}\}$
$w_1(e)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if }e=\{\text{palm},\text{thumb}\}\\
3 & \text{ if }e=\{\text{palm},\text{elbow}\}\\
2 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$
$\text{rot1}_v=\begin{cases}
\langle \text{thumb},\text{index},\text{middle},\text{ring},\text{pinkey},\text{elbow}\rangle & \text{ if }v=\text{palm}\\
\text{identity function} & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$

$G=(V_2,E_2,w_2,\text{rot2})$ with

$V_2=\{\text{tail},\text{left hindleg},\text{right hindleg},\text{right foreleg},\text{left foreleg},\text{body},\text{head}\}$
$E_2=\{\{\text{body},\text{other}\}\ |\ \text{other}\in V_2, \text{other}\neq \text{body}\}$
$w_2(e)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if }e=\{\text{body},\text{tail}\}\\
3 & \text{ if }e=\{\text{body},\text{head}\}\\
2 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$
$\text{rot2}_v=\begin{cases}
\langle \text{tail},\text{left hindleg},\text{right hindleg},\text{right foreleg},\text{left foreleg},\text{head}\rangle & \text{ if }v=\text{body}\\
\text{identity function} & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$

$D=(V_3,E_3,w_3,\text{rot3})$ with

$V_3=\{\text{head},\text{thorax},\text{right forewing},\text{right hindwing},\text{abdomen},\text{left hindwing},\text{left forewing}\}$
$E_3=\{\{\text{thorax},\text{other}\}\ |\ \text{other}\in V_3, \text{other}\neq \text{thorax}\}$
$w_3(e)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if }e=\{\text{thorax},\text{head}\}\\
3 & \text{ if }e=\{\text{thorax},\text{abdomen}\}\\
2 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$
$\text{rot3}_v=\begin{cases}
\langle \text{head},\text{right forewing},\text{right hindwing},\text{abdomen},\text{left hindwing},\text{left forewing}\rangle & \text{ if }v=\text{thorax}\\
\text{identity function} & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$

It can be seen that $H$ is isomorphic to $G$ with this bijection $\varphi:V_1\to V_2$ defined as follows:
$\varphi(v)=\begin{cases}
\text{body} & \text{ if }v=\text{palm}\\
\text{tail} & \text{ if }v=\text{thumb}\\
\text{left hindleg} & \text{ if }v=\text{index}\\
\text{right hindleg} & \text{ if }v=\text{middle}\\
\text{right foreleg} & \text{ if }v=\text{ring}\\
\text{left foreleg} & \text{ if }v=\text{pinkey}\\
\text{head} & \text{ if }v=\text{elbow}\\
\end{cases}$
However, notice that $H$ and $G$ are NOT isomorphic to $D$ because the head of the dragonfly doesn't agree with the thumb of the hand or the tail of the giraffe.
